# How do I downgrade an app on Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, downgrade

I found this existing question: [Downgrade camera app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780532/downgrade-camera-app), but it is not answered.

Specifically, I would like to downgrade the dialer/phone app, as it is not currently working due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dialer-app/+bug/1652635).

Comment: Have you tried `click register dialer-app <version>` in terminal?

Comment: I didn't know about the `click` command, it sounds very useful :) Oddly `click list` doesn't return anything mentioning dialer or phone, and `click info dialer-app` just returns `click_query_error-quark: Failed to canonicalize dialer-app: No such file or directory (0)`, which seems concerning. However, `click register dialer-app` doesn't complain it can't find `dialer-app`, but does require a version; I'm not sure how to find a suitable version number though.

Comment: After further investigation, `dialer-app` is a classic deb package not a click one (hence not finding it with `click`!), and was last updated in August, long before it broke, so it must be some other system change that has caused the problem.

Comment: Ok, the dialer-app is in the image and the last update of it was with OTA-13 (http://people.canonical.com/~lzemczak/landing-team/ota/ota-13.commitlog), not OTA-14 (http://people.canonical.com/~lzemczak/landing-team/ota/ota-14.commitlog). I'd say that the image flashing failed or some record in your phonebook has revealed a bug.

Comment: I asked on the mailing list, and it turned out the QML cache was corrupt, and deleting that made things work again. When I have a chance I'll write up what I've learned, both on this question and the launchpad bug.